# Remove time indication from datetime format in php

Tags: php, datetime

I allow users to choose the datetime format they want, so most of them have something like `D, d M Y H:i:s` , however, this could be anything.

In some cases though, I only want to display the date part, but still using the user's format.

Is there a simple way in PHP to remove the time part from a format like this?
I have thought of just removing all time elements from the format before formatting my date, but then again, how do you reliably remove separation chars like : or . , without affecting the format of the date (which of course may be anything exotic).

Comment: Personally I would give them the option to give a date time and a date only format.

Comment: That would indeed be the ideal case, but the user info is set in phpbb, and I prefer not to mess with that too much, to not make upgrading tooo difficult.

Comment: Someone will likely offer a great preg_replace solution with a regular expression, but I would think you could do some str_replace on the characters you know are time related (and look for non-space separators before / after them to remove).  The hour, minute, and second values are all known, and there's only about 10 of them to search for...

Comment: `date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($str));`

Comment: Indeed, thought about that, but was wondering if there is a robust solution that would also work for something like `H:i,d M Y`

Comment: And, if they choose the date format themselves, strtotime will not always return the correct results (dashes vs slashes, for example, cause different behavior)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the need to change or reformat, but just present how you want in the first place. Surely you provide them the options and therefore you control a finite (and presumably small) number of options? So just present the date only, no time (unless I've misunderstood)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to define a matching date format for every usual datetime format you encounter in your database. I don't know whether phpBB allows for completely custom format, that would make things a bit harder, but the average user will not fiddle with the PHP configuration options of `date()`.

Answer (score 0):

As always there are multiple approaches to solving your issue.

One approach could be to display a dropdown with 5 different formats. 
You then make a function that you can re-use to format according to user preference. 
So say I choose format nr. 2 in a dropdown, you simply just save that integer to my user settings and then make a function that you can call like this

```
$time_to_print = format_according_to_user_preference($preference,$timestamp);
```

Then you have a function with a couple of if clauses that sounds something like

```
function format_according_to_user_preference($preference,$timestamp){
    if($preference == 1){
    //American preference
    return date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($timestamp));
    }else if($preference == 2){
    //European preference 
    return date('d-m-Y H:i:s',strtotime($timestamp));
    }else{
    //some default preference just in case user hasen't set a wish 
    return date('Y-M-D H:i:s',strtotime($timestamp));
    }
}
```